# Is setCharacterEncoding() needed if charset is declared in content type?

Tags: java, servlets, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I am confusing with how to work well with encoding. Actually, I read some books and it says we should `setCharacterEncoding` before firstly `getParameter()`. While according to https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setCharacterEncoding%28java.lang.String%29

> **Overrides the name of the character encoding used in the body** of this
>   request. This method must be called prior to reading request
>   parameters or reading input using getReader(). Otherwise, it has no
>   effect.

So, I think since the container must know what the charset is in the HTTP body, so it seems we do not need `setCharacterEncoding()` if  charset is declared in the HTTP body.

I tried with my existing project, which will submit a request with a xml outputstream, I use

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "text/xml;charset=utf-8");
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
```

to encode the stream , and when I submit this request to a Servlet, `even though I do not call`request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");`  I can see that the Chinese Text is decoded well.

So it seems it works , but when I remove `charset=utf-8` from the content-type , it also works, this is even more confusing .

Here is how I read the xml stream into a map.

```
public  static Map<String, String>  parseXml(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Map<String,String> map=new HashMap<String,String>();
    InputStream is =request.getInputStream();
    SAXReader reader=new SAXReader();
    Document document=reader.read(is);      
    Element root =document.getRootElement();
    List<Element> elementList=root.elements();
    for(Element e: elementList){
        map.put(e.getName(), e.getText());
    }
    return map;     
}
```

Can anybody please explain a little bit about the how encoding works when Servlet handles POST request.And what will be the time we need explicitly setCharacterEncoding()?

PS: I run my client project and server project in Eclipse.

Comment: Try the same with a non UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: @Thilo , I tried `new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream(), "UTF-16")`, without setting charset or setCharacterEncoding , it also works to parse the Chinese.